# Endianness in binary processing in JS

Tags: javascript, binary, endianness

I'm writing an implementation of the AMF (Action Message Format) protocol in JS. Do I need to take endianness into account when parsing a byte stream from the network? The reason I ask is because, AFAIK, most systems these days are little-endian, but apparently all data coming over TCP/IP is in big-endian (network byte order).

Comment: As if it weren't painfully obviously already, I'm a bit of a n00b when it comes to binary processing and I haven't had a full formal CS education. Be gentle :)

Comment: All good, but I am pretty sure the TCP stack would take care of this for you.. Is there a specific issue this is causing? Can you post code/more information about a problem or are you just searching for more info?

Comment: No specific issue - just trying to be prudent :)

Comment: No probs. Yeah well as I said I think the TCP stack should take care of this. But it will be different depending on the device. x86 is little endian, where as I am pretty sure ARM is big-endian. Hopefully someone can shed a little more light on this more you.

Answer (score 0):

If you're transferring bytes, they're seen as bytes. The endianness is determined by the data source's implementation, so it could be either big or little endian.

Regardless, the accepted norm for TCP/IP transfers is big endian and most transfers follow this rule.

I would suggest that the easiest way to determine the endianness of your source data is to go ahead and try to parse it and compare your result with a sample.